# Pass class object to different dll

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I have a little problem understanding what I should do.

I have a main project `MainProj`.
And another project called `PluginHandler` who has an `IPlugin` interface.

What I'm trying to achieve is to "send" an object called `Network` from `MainProj` to each plugin that implement the `IPlugin` interface.

My problem is what type should I write in the `IPlugin`, because it's in a different project I can't just say `Network` - and I can't reference it because I need a reference to the `PluginHandler` in the `MainProj`, in order to instantiate each plugin (using reflections)

Any ideas?

Comment: Where you have defined `Network`? According to me you need to define it in your `PluginHandler` project. then add the reference of `PluginHandler` in your main project.

Comment: In MainProj\Model\Network

Comment: Add reference from PluginHandler project to MainProj and make sure that your classes in PluginHandler project are `public` or you won't be able to use them cause by default classes have access modifier set to internal.

Comment: What would the plugin be able to do with a `Network` object? Does it need to know about it? Could `Network` implement a useful interface that the plugins could know about? You haven't really given us enough context to help you properly.

Comment: But I'll need a reference to the PluginHandler in my MainProj so I can insantiate new plugins dll that implement that interface

Comment: @JonSkeet the plugin should be able to use all the data inside Network object (it has lot's of objects from my MainProj\Model)

Comment: Use dynamic instead if it is just one class

Comment: it would seem you have a class called `Network` not an object.

Comment: @Yogevnn: So your plugins will need a reference to the main project, right? Can you make your `IPlugin` generic, so that each plugin can indicate that it's able to handle a particular type? That way you wouldn't need the PluginHandler project to know about the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a "shared library". So instead of

- MainProj

  - Network
- PluginHandler

  - IPlugin
- Plugin

you should have

- MainProj
- PluginHandler

  - IPlugin
- Plugin
- Common

  - Network

So you place the `Network` class inside the `Common` project and reference this by all other projects.

Comment: wow that sound's nice...I'll try that and update if it worked!

Comment: I use the same pattern in all my plugin apps and it works fine. You could also put `Network` in the same assembly as `IPlugin`, but I like to keep them separated.

Comment: Yes the pattern looks great if it is seperated, it sounds like it's going to work but i need to make some changes in my app so it will take a while to check, thank you for your answer! I'll update as soon as i'm don

Comment: I'm not done refactoring yet, but just a question that i got along the way, if IPlugin has a reference to Network and has a member Network net, how will each plugin use that Network object?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. If `Network` is defined in `Common` and this is referenced by all other projects it can be used like any other type...

Comment: Well...I guess the hours on the computer took their toll...sorry for the question and thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the other project as a reference in your `MainProj`
and then add a using statement to import that namespace into your file.

When adding a reference you can either choose a dll or just choose another project.

[How to add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

[How to add a using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: But I'll need a reference to the PluginHandler in my MainProj so I can insantiate new plugins dll that implement that interface

Comment: Refer to the dll compiled from PluginHandler